# Spring @DependsOn For Different Profiles

Tags: java, spring

I have two different beans for the same class with different configurations depending on the given profile.

```
@Bean
@Profile("!local")
public VaultPropertySource vaultPropertySource(ConfigurableApplicationContext context)

@Bean
@Profile("local")
public VaultPropertySource vaultPropertySourceLocal(ConfigurableApplicationContext context)
```

I have another bean that depends on **VaultPropertySource** instance.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@DependsOn({"vaultPropertySource"})
public class VaultPropertyReader {

    private final VaultPropertySource vaultPropertySource;
```

The problem is bean names are different and it only works on the first instance. How can I make it work on both profiles? Can I make it depend on the bean class instead of bean name?

Comment: `@ConditionalOnBean(VaultPropertySource.class)` perhaps should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the profiles not on the bean but on the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!local")
class VaultConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public VaultPropertySource vaultPropertySource(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        // return real PropertySource
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("local")
class LocalVaultConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public VaultPropertySource vaultPropertySource(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
         // return local PropertySource
    }
}
```

That probably helps.